# can i add external dll to npapi plugin , that suppos to be installed in the browser?

Tags: c++, dll, npapi

Im building plugin to FF and Chrome , this plugin needs to call API methods that are in external dll/so . can i bundle that npapi plugin with external dll in the plug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can.  Keep in mind that some people seem to have trouble getting a linked DLL to load from the plugin DLL directory, so you might need to delay load it and set the DLL search path on plugin startup to search in the directory the plugin is in, but you can install the dependency along with the plugin DLL.

Comment: hi thanks for the answer do you know any examples that shows this?

Comment: I don't have an example -- I try to avoid it, myself.  However, to set the DLL directory you need http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx9zd12s.aspx describes how to delayload a dll (at least in command line terms; it's not hard to do in the gui either)